# "Style" Error for Displaying AJAX Popup (vb.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, gridview

I am getting an error when I try Running some code in VB, I have some VB code that tells my Griview to Add a label that says "Insert Email"
in th last Collumn in any Row that doesn't contain an email address:

I also have some code which I want to Open up an Ajax Modal Popup Box once the label in the Collumn has been clicked:

This is my Updated Code (Which still does not Work):

```
'----------------------------------------

For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
If GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Text = "&nbsp;" Then
Dim lbl As String
lbl = "Insert Email"
GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Text = lbl

e.Row.Cells(9).Attributes("OnMouseOver") = "this.style.textDecoration='underline'; this.style.cursor='hand';"
e.Row.Cells(9).Attributes("OnMouseOut") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"

e.Row.Cells(9).Attributes.Add("OnClick", "document.getElementById('" + deletePopup.ClientID + "').style.visibility= 'True'")

End If
Next

'----------------------------------------
```

The Error Is:

> Error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference

I think it is refering to this line:

> ```
> e.Row.Cells(9).Attributes.Add("OnClick", "document.getElementById('deletePopup').Style.Visible = True'")
> ```

---

---

Here is the ASPX Code for the Modal Popup it should be opening:

```
    <div id="deletePopup" runat="server" class="modalPopup" 
    style="padding: 2px; width: 396px;" visible="false">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="ServiceID" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenDesc" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Type in an Email:"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="370px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="UpdateEmailBtn" runat="server" Text="Update Email" />
<asp:Button ID="cancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
</div>
```

I was hoping to get some assistance with this please. Thankyou in advance...

Im not quite sure if I am typing my code correctly...

Comment: You most likely already checked. But are you certain an element with id of 'deletePopup' actually exists?

Comment: You should try `document.getElementById("deletePopup").style.display = "none"` , but before that check if you have `deletePopup` element in page.

Comment: Propertys are case-sensitive ;)

Comment: Then use `deletePopup.ClientID` instead of `deletePopup`.

Comment: Yes it is being referenced Correctly, I just dont get why it's not working. @ArindamNayak

Comment: Still No Luck @ArindamNayak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got your issue.

I can see that, you had used following.

`<div id="deletePopup" runat="server" class="modalPopup" style="padding: 2px; width: 396px;" visible="false">`

When you use `visible=false`, that will remove `deletePopup` element from `DOM`.

> If this property is false, the server control is not rendered. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible(v=vs.100).aspx)

And since that does not exist in DOM, you are getting error - `Unable to get property 'style' of undefined`. If you want to make it visible using javascript, then you need to make it hidden using clientside code only (`css`), like following.

`<div id="deletePopup" runat="server" class="modalPopup" style="padding: 2px; width: 396px;display:none;" >`

And make it visible using the following javascript.

`e.Row.Cells(9).Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + deletePopup.ClientID +"').style.display = 'block'")`

*As a side note:* If you need to make it visible using server side code, you can use `deletePopup.Visible = True`.